# How do I get the ID of the selected dynamic radiobutton VB.NET with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, page-lifecycle

I have dynamically generated radiobuttons, How can I get the id if the dynamic radiobuttons in a textbox (textbox2) when I cick on the selected button.
the code below only works for generating the controls (radio and textboxes), I mean the btnload works but the btnselected does not work (the dynamic controls just vanish and textbox2 dispalys nothing.).

```
<html>
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">         
                ​<asp:Panel ID="container" runat="server">

                </asp:Panel>       
            <div>
               <asp:Button ID="btnload" runat="server" Text="Load" />  
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                no of loops</div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnselected" runat="server" Text="selected" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="margin-top: 26px"></asp:TextBox>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

Protected Sub getradioId_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnload.Click

        Dim tbl As New Table
        tbl.Width = 500

        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Do Until i = TextBox1.Text
            Dim tblrow As New TableRow
            tblrow.Width = 80%

            Dim tblcellrad As New TableCell
            tblcellrad.Width = 100

            Dim tblcellname As New TableCell
            tblcellname.Width = 300

            Dim cand As New TextBox
            cand.ID = i

            i += 1
            Dim rad As New RadioButton   'generate controls (radiobuttons and textbox)
            rad.GroupName = "one"
            rad.ID = i
            rad.Text = "rad" & i
            cand.Text = "candidate " & i.ToString

            If i Mod 2 = 1 Then      'set row colour
                tblrow.Style.Add("background-color", "#EEEEEE")
            Else
                tblrow.Style.Add("background-color", "#E0E0E0")
            End If

            tblcellrad.Controls.Add(rad)    'add controls to cells
            tblcellname.Controls.Add(cand)

            tblrow.Controls.Add(tblcellname) 'add cells to rows
            tblrow.Controls.Add(tblcellrad)


            tbl.Controls.Add(tblrow) 'add row to table
            container.Controls.Add(tbl)

        Loop
    End Sub

Protected Sub btnselected_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnselected.Click
        Dim radios = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).AsQueryable()

        For Each r As RadioButton In radios
            If r.Checked Then
                TextBox2.Text = r.ID.ToString
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If `btnselected_Click` is the event triggered when selection occurs you then can cast the `sender` object in the event doing something like:

```
Dim selectedRdo = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you recreating the buttons each time? Dynamic controls must be recreated on each and every postback. They need to be created at the right time, usually the OnLoad event is the last I will use (Page_Load is too late). You have to do it then in order for it to exist and be tied to the viewstate in time for the second postback event to be called, where the posted data is matched up with the controls. They also have to have the exact same ID each and every time when they are created or else it doesn't work.

Now, in your case, to match up the radio button with a textbox should be pretty since since your textbox has an id, which is an integer, and your radiobutton also has an id, which is the same as textbox.

The first issue though is ensuring you create the controls correctly each and every time.